# Count Unique elements in pytorch Tensor

Tags: pytorch

Suppose I have the following tensor: `y = torch.randint(0, 3, (10,))`. How would you go about counting the 0's 1's and 2's in there?

The only way I can think of is by using `collections.Counter(y)` but was wondering if there was a more "pytorch" way of doing this. A use case for example would be when building the confusion matrix for predictions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`torch.unique`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique.html) with the `return_counts` option:

```
>>> x = torch.randint(0, 3, (10,))
tensor([1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1])

>>> x.unique(return_counts=True)
(tensor([0, 1, 2]), tensor([2, 6, 2]))
```